# How to handle large number of vector drawables in Android

Tags: android, optimization, android-resources, android-vectordrawable

I am building an Android app in which I have many vector drawble in XML format (around 10000 files). Currently, I put them in the resource folder and it takes very long time to build the app.
Is there any better way to handle this?

Comment: some drawables will be availabe in `@android:drawable/`. use it

Comment: Which version of support library are you using and what's your min sdk version?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving them into a separate `module`? By the way, maybe you can try putting them on the server and downloading them just on demand, and just having the really main ones in your APK.